# Spring form with thymeleaf not binding right, throwing exception: Parameter is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, thymeleaf

I have two views, one to book appointments and one to show them in a calendar view. After the booking was successful, there's a confirmation shown. The confirmation then forwards to the calendar view. I want to pass the booking infos as parameters to the calendar view so it can display the new booking accordingly in the calendar, but a null exception is thrown in that step.

I copied the template of a working form. I inspected the web request, all the necessary data is there, I think it's just not binding right.

```
data class EventAppointmentSearchRequest (val startDateTime: LocalDateTime, val endDateTime: LocalDateTime, val rooms: List<Room>)
```

```
    /**
     * Gets called when confirming a booking to add it to the DB.
     */
    @PostMapping("/roomBookingConfirmation")
    fun roomBookingConfirmation(model: Model, @ModelAttribute roomBookingRequest: RoomBookingRequest): String {

        makeBooking(roomBookingRequest)

        val date = roomBookingRequest.datetimeFrom
        val start = roomBookingRequest.datetimeFrom.minusDays(date.dayOfWeek.value.toLong())
        val end = roomBookingRequest.datetimeFrom.plusDays(7 - date.dayOfWeek.value.toLong())

        model.addAttribute("eventAppointmentSearchRequest", EventAppointmentSearchRequest(
                startDateTime = start,
                endDateTime = end,
                rooms = listOf(roomRepository.findByRoomName(roomBookingRequest.roomNr))
        ))
        return "roomBookingConfirmation"
    }
```

```
    /**
     * Displays the appointments in the calendar view according to the request
     */
    @PostMapping("/calendarView")
    fun calendarView(model: Model, @ModelAttribute eventAppointmentSearchRequest: EventAppointmentSearchRequest): String {
        // THIS THROWS THE EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method ...requests.EventAppointmentSearchRequest.<init>, parameter startDateTime
        ...
    }
```

```
    <!-- /*@thymesVar id="eventAppointmentSearchRequest" type="de.tudarmstadt.pvw.tulpe.soonToBeArtifactory.requests.EventAppointmentSearchRequest"*/ -->
    <form th:action="@{/calendarView}" method="post" th:object="${eventAppointmentSearchRequest}" id="forwardToCalendar" style="grid-column: span 4">
        <H1 th:text="#{roomBooking.bookingConfirmed}">
            Booking confirmed.
        </H1>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#" th:text="#{roomBooking.nowRedirecting}" onclick="forwardToCalendar()">Redirecting to
                calendarView in </a> <b id="secondsLeft">7</b>
            <input type="hidden" th:field="${eventAppointmentSearchRequest.startDateTime}" th:name="startDateTime" th:value="${eventAppointmentSearchRequest.startDateTime}">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="${eventAppointmentSearchRequest.endDateTime}" th:name="endDateTime" th:value="${eventAppointmentSearchRequest.endDateTime}">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="${eventAppointmentSearchRequest.rooms}" name="rooms[]" th:each="room: ${eventAppointmentSearchRequest.rooms}" th:value="${room.RoomId}">
        </div>
        ...
    </form>
```

I expect the form to just be bound correctly, I can see all the necessary data to use the constructor of EventAppointmentSearchRequest in the web inspector of my browser. Actual output is this error message:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method ...requests.EventAppointmentSearchRequest., parameter startDateTime

Comment: This might help you (not using thymeleaf though) - https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice for the two date hidden inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{endDateTime}">
```

As for the third, th:field takes precedence over name and value attributes, if you look closely into the generated HTML, you'll see that the value is identical for each room hidden input, and it's the toString() on the list of Rooms. This is clearly wrong, and you need to specify each attribute of Room that you want to submit, have a look at the following article: https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list

I don't see the point in transmitting the details of the booking 2 more times between the client and server, I'd just pass a booking ID to the calendar page and have it load all the details...